# write post request body to a text file with node js file system in express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

trying to write a post request body to a text file using node js file system but i keep on getting this error and i don't even know what it means : Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:393:5)
at ServerResponse.setHeader (node:_http_outgoing:644:11)
can any one help? here is my code

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
const message_control_post = require('../controllers/messageControl.js')
const { body, validationResult } = require('express-validator')
const fs = require('fs')
const fsPromises = require('fs').promises
const path = require('path')


/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index');
});

router.post('/', message_control_post.message_control)

router.post('/test', (req, res, next) => {
  const message = `${req.body.name} sent ${req.body.email} this message: ${req.body.msg}`
  fs.writeFile(path.join(__dirname, 'files', 'msg.txt'), message, (err) => {
    if (err) {
      return next(err)
    } else {
      console.log(message)
    }
    
  })
  next()
}, (req, res, next) => {
  res.send(req.body)
});
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error: Can't set headers after they are sent to the client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7042340/error-cant-set-headers-after-they-are-sent-to-the-client)

Answer (score 0):

The callback - last param of `fs.writeFile` will be called after the `next()`. So here the flow of your code:

`fs.writeFile -> next -> res.send -> next(err) -> res.send`

The second `res.send` then throw an `Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]`

I think your code should look like this:

```
router.post('/test', (req, res) => {
  const message = `${req.body.name} sent ${req.body.email} this message: ${req.body.msg}`
  fs.writeFile(path.join(__dirname, 'files', 'msg.txt'), message, (err) => {
    if (err) {
      return res.send(error);
    } else {
      res.send(req.body)
    }
  })
});
```